# Microsoft Graph API - Approve Moderation Request

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I want to be able approve a moderation request through Graph API. I have referred to [Approve Moderation Request](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/725086ec-7288-46c3-9ec5-5ad5e93786d0/graph-api-approve-moderation-request). I was not able to get it to work. Although, there is a PowerShell script available at [EWS Managed API and Powershell How-To Series Part 11 Moderation](https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2012/07/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to.html)  that I managed to get working.

This is not a supported feature in Graph API and therefore requires some tinkering. I would like some guidance on how to do this.

This is the JSON I am sending to the end point https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail

```
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Approve:MessageName"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Microsoft Exchange",
                "address": "systemmailbox@domain.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "id": "Binary 0x31",
            "value": "7gd324tgcxJJNkEuxk2DP2Xk+M/fxw=="
        },
        {
            "id": "String 0x001A",
            "value": "IPM.Note.Microsoft.Approval.Reply.Approve"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the response I receive

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidRecipients",
        "message": "At least one recipient isn't valid., A message can't be sent because it contains no recipients.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-08-19T23:40:07",
            "request-id": "7g5h732v-6uhb-3212-b6f1-43f6eeb139wq"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax issue in your Json request eg look closely at the Message after subject you have a closing } which means the only thing your posting is the subject of the message it should be

```html
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Approve:MessageName",
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Microsoft Exchange",
                    "address": "address.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
            {
                "id": "Binary 0x31",
                "value": "7gd324tgcxJJNkEuxk2DP2Xk+M/fxw=="
            },
            {
                "id": "String 0x001A",
                "value": "IPM.Note.Microsoft.Approval.Reply.Approve"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Additional

To make this work correctly you need to get the Approval Request from an app rovers mailbox for the Graph a query like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'String 0x001a' and ep/value eq 'IPM.Note.Microsoft.Approval.Request')&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter%3D(Id eq 'Binary 0x0031') or (Id eq 'String 0x0E1D'))
```

This will give you the report tag 0x0031 value that you need to use in your Send and you also need to include the Approve Verb Extended property

```
{
                    id = "String {00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8524"
                    value = "Approve"
 }
```

I converted the script from my blog which I'll get around to posting this week that just approves the last email in a Mailbox you can look at it https://github.com/gscales/Powershell-Scripts/blob/master/Graph101/Moderation.ps1 (look at Invoke-ApproveModerationRequest)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Glen. When I send the request I get this message **'Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.'**

I also wanted to know for the id "Binary 0x31" do I provide the ID of the email ?

Comment: When using the PowerShell Script I do not have issue of the message not being delivered. Additionally, do I need to include more properties to approve the email ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Glen. It works now ! I was wondering are there any resources to learn more about how to use singleValueExtendedProperties and how to construct the URLs to retrieve other information. I assume we can retrieve different properties from an email with the information available in a tool like MFCMapi

Comment: Yes a MAPI editor is the best resource, the Exchange protocol documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprotlp/229f77ea-6518-4fe7-84fe-bd535fc6c32e is useful for breaking down what the values of particular binary properties mean. Also while this is for MAPI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-property-overview understanding the 3 different property types tagged, named (String and Lid) will help a lot.

Comment: Thank you Glen. I will take a look